# NSIS DELETE all files by extension

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to delete all files with a specific extension in a folder. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878496/nsis-find-all-txt-files) question on how to get all txt files and I thought about using that to get all files by extension and removing them, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between listing and deleting files:

```
FindFirst $0 $1 "$INSTDIR\*.txt"
loop:
  StrCmp $1 "" done
  StrCpy $2 "$INSTDIR\$1"
  IfFileExists "$2\*.*" +2 ; A directory?
    Delete "$2"
  FindNext $0 $1
  Goto loop
done:
FindClose $0
```

That being said, the documentation says wildcards are supported so you should be able to just do

```
Delete "$INSTDIR\*.txt"
```